# Podio: How do I add a comment to an item I just created using the API for Python 3?

Tags: python, podio

For Python 3 I can't seem to find a Comment-class anywhere in the API, like what is referred to in the [documentation](https://developers.podio.com/doc/comments/add-comment-to-object-22340). I've tried a number of different ways that I can think of as guesses on how to add the comment using the Item.create- and Item.update-methods but nothing I've tried has worked. So, how would I do this?

Neither can I find anything called "commentable ID" or "commentable type". Are those simply the item-ID and item-type of the item I want to add the comment to?
 As a newbie-programmer, the documentation is not really very easy to interpret.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you refer to 
https://developers.podio.com/doc/comments/add-comment-to-object-22340 , which is explaining adding comments to object.

Eg:
PodioComment::create( $ref_type, $ref_id, $attributes = array() );
ref_type may be App or Item
Ref_id id corresponding id such as app_id or itemid
and the parameters as 
{
  "value": The comment to be made,

"external_id": The external id of the comment, if any,

"file_ids": Temporary files that have been uploaded and should be attached to this comment,

[

```
{file_id},

.... (more file ids)
```

],

"embed_id": [OPTIONAL] The id of an embedded link that has been created with the Add an mebed operation in the Embed area,

"embed_url": The url to be attached

}

In response you get the comment_id. If you wanna edit the existing comment use the comment_id in request as described.

Comment: So for example this would be valid code in Python? podio.Comment.create( 'Item', 5555555, {"value": "This is a comment"}). That would make sense I guess, but I can't find the class "Comment"